# Infinity Preloader

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, preloader

I have a issue in preloader. And donot know how to correct it.

Problem is. Preloader is showing infinity while using Chrome. I saw some solutions like gZip Compression in server.

I want to know any other solution from flash side. because i'm developing game and we can play it anywhere.

I want the solution a soon as possible. Someone help me to do it.

Comment: I'm sorry but i have now idea how to help you without more informations

Answer (score 0):

When I was struggling with prealoaders, [this](http://www.senocular.com/flash/tutorials/preloading/) page helped me tons for as2  and concepts in general, [this](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3preloader/) one helped me doing it in as3

The basic idea is to listen to the progress event and do simple calculations using the total amount you need to download and the current bytes you already have.

Comment: @RDC Please try to avoid linkifying the text "this" in your edits. Make the link text something meaningful and descriptive, like the article title. Where that doesn't read well it can be helpful to break the links out into a "See also" block.

Answer (score 0):

You may occasionally get infinity in these calculations when the bytesTotal has not been correctly populated.

It's good practice to do something like

```
var loadper:Number = 0;
if (this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal >= 0) 
{
    loadper = Math.round((this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded/this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal)*100);
}
...
```

There are many reasons you could be getting 0 bytes returned as the total but usually it has to do with the way you are delivering files from your server.